# How to show dialled call list in recycler view using fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to display dialed call records from my mobile and i got success on it. But the problem now is that when i am sending the data to my getter setter class it is show some error and i dont know how to get rid of it.

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;

public OneFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragRecycler1);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    getDialledList();
}

private void getDialledList() {
    List<CallList> callList = new ArrayList();
    CallList logList;
    String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    ContentResolver cR = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Cursor cursor = cR.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, strOrder, null);
    //managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,strOrder);
    int phName = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int phNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int phType = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int phDate = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int phDuration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(phName);
        String number = cursor.getString(phNumber).toString();
        String date = cursor.getString(phDate);
        Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(date));
        String duration = cursor.getString(phDuration);
        String type = cursor.getString(phType);
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(type);
        //Log.e(String.valueOf(getActivity()),"Values :" +temp);
        if(dircode == 1){
            logList = new CallList();
            callList.add(number); //getting java.lang.string error here
        }
        RecyclerAdapter1 recyclerAdapter1 = new RecyclerAdapter1(callList,getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter1);
    }
    cursor.close();
    //callList.add(logList);
}
}
```

Comment: Show what error are you getting

Comment: Change variable 'callList'  type to 'java.util.List<java.util.String>' this is the error

Comment: ^ Please add that error, in a formatted block, in the question itself please.

Comment: Error:(89, 25) error: no suitable method found for add(String)
method Collection.add(CallList) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CallList)
method List.add(CallList) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CallList)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `number` which is a `String` to `callList` which is an `ArrayList<CallList>`. Either change it to `ArrayList<String>` if you only care for the number, or do `callList.add(logList)` because `logList` is a `CallList` object